# Dynamic Substring in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I am working on a project where I have the two below tables:

```
#temp1:
```

[image]

```
#temp2:
```

[image]

So for every client on #temp2 table, I have to check if the substring(outcome,1,12) matches with text1/text2/text3/text4 of #temp1 table. And if they match the then concatenate text1/text2/text3/text4(replace the matching substring on #temp1 with outcome of #temp2). The final output is to be as below:

```
#output desired:
```

[image]

So for CID 1001, the substring(#temp2.outcome,1,12) = SOP201800205 matches with #temp1.text2 = SOP201800205. So my output should be

```
   Concat(#temp1.text1,#temp2.outcome)
```

My trial here in rextester demo:

https://rextester.com/CAEP69354

Any help?!

Comment: You are getting some error ? or what? Is it not clear in your question.

Comment: I am not getting any error. I'm just unable to complete my code. You cna check the link provided

Comment: I don't understand at all what you are trying to do here. Could you make your sample data a bit easier to decipher? 20+ character strings of random characters is really hard to follow. Can you also try to explain what the logic is here? I can't understand how those two tables relate. It does seem that the biggest issue is your first table is denormalized and violates 1NF with repeating columns.

Comment: @SeanLange ok I will make the test data simple

Comment: @SeanLange Pls chk this link - https://rextester.com/QFI78492 Simplified the test data

Comment: What should the output be from the new sample data? Seems like the answer below from Eric Brandt is pretty much what you are looking for?

Comment: To @SeanLange's point, I feel like I'm pretty close. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're really trying to find out if any of the values in `#temp1` are completely contained in the `outcome` of `#temp2`. Despite your `SUBSTRING` parameters, I think you don't care how long the strings are, so I used the length of the `#temp1` value to set the parameter for the `#temp2` `SUBSTRING`.

If that's correct, then you just need a more robust `CASE` statement. This should work for you:

```
select
    t1.cid,
    case 
        when t1.text1 = substring(t2.outcome,1,len(t1.text1))
            then concat(t2.outcome,' ',t1.text2,' ',t1.text3,' ',t1.text4)
        when t1.text2 = substring(t2.outcome,1,len(t1.text2))
            then concat(t1.text1,' ',t2.outcome, ' ',t1.text3,' ',t1.text4)
        when t1.text3 = substring(t2.outcome,1,len(t1.text3))
            then concat(t1.text1,' ',t1.text2, ' ',t2.outcome,' ',t1.text4)
        when t1.text4 = substring(t2.outcome,1,len(t1.text4))
            then concat(t1.text1,' ',t1.text2, ' ',t1.text3,' ',t2.outcome)
        else concat(t1.text1,' ',t1.text2, ' ',t1.text3,' ',t1.text4)
    end
from #temp1 t1
join #temp2 t2 on t1.cid = t2.cid;
```

Rextester: https://rextester.com/BIR87919

Comment: Eric, this helped me. Sorry about the delay. But yes, I want to compare if the whole of #temp1 is in the outcome and concatenate with the rest of the data.

Comment: As long as it helped, time doesn't matter. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have only one case where substring of text1 or text2 or text3 or text4
is equal to t2.outcome of CID

```
select
t1.cid,
substring(t1.text1,1,12),
substring(t1.text2,1,12),
substring(t1.text3,1,12),
substring(t1.text4,1,12),
substring(t2.outcome,1,12) as outcome,
case when substring(t1.text1,1,12) = substring(t2.outcome,1,12) then 'text1 = outcome'
end,
case 
     when substring(t1.text2,1,12) = substring(t2.outcome,1,12) then 'text2 = outcome'

end,
case when substring(t1.text3,1,12) = substring(t2.outcome,1,12) then 'text3 = outcome'
end,
case when substring(t1.text4,1,12) = substring(t2.outcome,1,12) then 'text4 = outcome'
end

from #temp1 t1
join #temp2 t2 on t1.cid = t2.cid
```

I think you have wrong substring 
do you expect  `substring(t1.text2,1,12) = substring(t2.outcome,1,12)`
or  `substring(t1.text2,1,11) = substring(t2.outcome,1,11)`
do you relay want to check substring substring(t1.text,1,12) ?